# Не отображается слайдер на главной странице

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, slider, плагин

Помогите решить проблему. Перестал отображаться слайдер от плагина Revolution Slider на главной странице сайта. Возможно, перестал отображаться после обновления шаблона, т.к. вообще не заметил, как пропал. До этого все работало нормально. Настройки видимости не трогал, в чем может быть проблема? Сайт axiomacenter.com

**Скрин того, как было**
[image: Скриншот того, как было]

**Скрин того, как стало**
[image: Скриншот того, как стало]

Answer (score 0):

Проблема найдена и решена. Ругался на jquery.js

"You have some jquery.js library include that comes after the Slider Revolution files js inclusion.". "To fix this, you can:

1. Set 'Module General Options' -> 'Advanced' -> 'jQuery & OutPut Filters' -> 'Put JS to Body' to on
2. Find the double jQuery.js inclusion and remove it